# parameters of queuing theory

Tags: probability-distributions, queueing-theory

Consider a queuing system that follows the model M / M / 1 wherein the average time between consecutive arrivals is 12 secons and the average service time is 3 seconds.

$\lambda=\displaystyle\frac{1}{12}$ and $\mu=\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}$

What is the probability that a customer has to wait in queue?
My options are: $$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$$$$\displaystyle\frac{2}{3}$$ $$\displaystyle\frac{3}{4}$$$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{4}$$$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}$$

but i obtained that $$w_q=\rho*w=\displaystyle\frac{1}{4}*4=1$$ what's wrong?

What is the probability that a customer has to wait more than six seconds in queue?
How do i calculate this?

Answer (score 0):

You calculated the average waiting time in the queue instead of the desired probability. The probability that the server is busy upon a customer arrival is simply $\rho$.